# Copying numerous drives to one HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-cloning

In the last month I took out about 5 HDDs from my laptops and replaced them with SSD drives. Now these drives are very old, and the heads are worn out, so working with the data that's on them seems risky. Therefore I want to copy all the partitions from these drives in their entirety to a new 1 or 2 TB drive. How can this be done, so that these partitions, once their on the new drive, remain bootable (a few partitions have an OS on them)? Is it enough to copy everything that's on these drives, including the boot files to a new partition?

The operating system on the partitions are Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you want to boot up old partitions from laptops on your PC. That will introduce some troubles due to hardware differences even if you've succeeded in copying all the partitions into one HDD.

It is not impossible technically, but not as effective as P2V either. Anyway, if you want that, I'd like to suggest the possible way.

First of all, GRUB2 is available for multiboot environment. There are similar tools like this but I think this is easy to use. http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/ To use this tool, of course you need a way to clone your existing partitions to a big drive, and CloneZilla may help you. http://clonezilla.org/ CloneZilla has a fancy mode named "CloneZilla Live" which makes you run the tool directly from USB or CD.

So the overall procedure will be like this:

1. Using CloneZilla Live, copy all the existing partitions to your new drive. The drive will have multiple partitions, of course. It's important to keep the original partition size on each cloning.
2. Set up GRUB2 on the new drive and configure it carefully to make all the partition bootable by adding menus manually.

After doing that, you will get the boot option as you wanted. However, I don't personally recommend this as it's not guaranteed to run due to the hardware issues I mentioned. I still believe that P2V conversion is better for your case as you're running old partitions with a new machine.

Comment: As I said in the comment below, I'm looking for a way to copy the partitions and make them bootable in the normal way, of choosing an OS out of many.

Comment: That means that you want to boot up old partitions from laptops on your PC. That will introduce some troubles due to hardware differences even if you've succeeded in copying all the partitions into one. It is not impossible technically, but not as effective as P2V either.

Comment: As far as I know, all I need to do is have the PC set to the SATA mode (AHCI/IDE) for the right OS and these partitions should be accessible. Problem with a virtual machine is it requires extra software to manage.

Comment: Partitions should be accessible, but "boot up" from those partitions is a totally different issue. You will need to manage the hardware difference anyway, which is usually troublesome and time-consuming. And mulitiboot & partition cloning require extra software too. (But I understand why you mentioned that point.)

Comment: I've connected drives taken from laptops to desktop motherboards and I booted into the laptop OS and it worked normally (except for some licensing issues, but that's manageable).

Comment: If you've tested it and proved that the issue was not severe on your case, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the free tool Disk2VHD from Microsoft (SysInternals tool).  It can convert the existing drives into bootable VHDs (it's not TECHNICALLY supported as a mechanism to go from physical to virtual, but I've used it for such purposes before and don't recall ever having a problem doing so).

Additional benefit, unlike the VMWare tool, you can EASILY mount the VHD files in Windows 7 and Windows 8 (and Windows Server 2008 and later) as additional "disk drives" and gain virtually instant read/write random access to the files (even 7Zip can open them and extract files as if it's one big archive).

Or you can create a VM in Client Hyper-V or Hyper-V Server and attach them as the OS/Hard Drives.  It's also fast and creates files that are only (relatively) slightly larger than the total amount of used disk space on the original drive.

Comment: I don't care about ease of access. I'm just looking for a way to copy those partitions in such a fashion, that when I power up my PC I will get the typical option of booting into each OS.

Comment: First, let me apologize for even suggesting you could boot them. Odds are the OS came with the computer in which case the license prohibits their use on other hardware. If per chance that wasn't the case, then you should look into Boot to VHD (doesn't work with VMware) - It requires Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise (and probably Win8 Enterprise), but you can configure the boot loader to boot to (provide a menu of) VHDs. That said, as noted in a subsequent comment, you would likely have issues booting since you'll have massive hardware changes. Based on info so far, your plan is flawed.

Comment: It is flawed, if my understanding of how multiple partitions, each with an OS, will work. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from my experience, if I have two partitions, each one having an OS, I will have a menu in which I can choose which OS to boot into. This was the case with Windows 2000 and Windows XP. Regarding the license, does this mean that even as a VM, there will be licensing issues?

Comment: Yes and no. You need to have a boot loader because the boot sector loads information as to which partition to boot from. There used to be programs that did this like System Commander was one. But I have 20+ years experience and there is NO WAY I would do what you're asking (as I understand it) for myself. It'd require a level of technical know-how and effort that wouldn't be worth my time.  Give yourself a break and look into VMs.  But again, you will need to consult the license agreements to determine what can and cannot be virtualized without purchasing additional software/software licenses.